# UV Unwrapping issue

Tags: texturing, uv

I am making this medieval cart with a cross. I want to add a wood texture to the cart, but when I unwrap it, it has a really weird shape on the UV editor (even tho the cart is a very simple shape), and the texture is all bended and weird. How do I solve this? 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got a lot of double vertices, remove doubles in edit mode[image]